Strong And Weak Symbol Conflicts
Consider a scenario where I have two separate files in my C/C++ project:

The first file defines two global variables: int x = 7; and int y = 5;.
The second file defines a global variable double x;.

In this case, we have a strong int x versus a weak double x. Choosing the strong int x will lead to issues, as modifying x in the second file will overwrite memory. (Could possibly change int y)
(Edit: I've encountered a question discussing this scenario, but I'd like to focus on a different question rather than continuing with what I've mentioned previously.)
However, if both int x and double x are declared as weak symbols, and let's assume that the linker chooses double x, can we conclude that no issues will arise?

ODR violation is UB.  Issues will probably arise.

Please don't tag two different languages. Only tag the language you are using.

@Eljay can you give example of what could go worng?

If you are unlucky, it could appear to work.  If you are lucky, it'll crash.

There is no rule (AFAIK) which is defining for the linker which of the multiple weak symbols to pick. So theoretically it might work on the odd numbered days, but not on the even ones.

@Eljay I'm wondering why the linker doesn't output a diagnostic message like when you define two functions with the same name in two different c files (AKA compilation units)

@EugeneSh. That's precisely my question. If we assume that the linker has chosen double x, can I confidently assert that no issues will arise?

But you can't assume that. In order to assume that your double declaration has to be strong. But then you know the answer.

You'd need to use a tool like ORC to report on ODR violations.  Most (or all?) linkers don't do that.

@EugeneSh. Understood. I'm simply exploring the scenario where the linker chooses double x to understand the potential implications.

@LittleMonkey my advice is: avoid global variables as much as possible.

If you must use global variables, avoid generic names like x.  Prefix them with a unique name identifying the one place where they are defined.
